# How to find the vertices of an edge and if either of those is a leaf node a in JUNG Graph?

Tags: java, jung

I am working with JUNG Graph. The problem I am working on can be defined as follows:

> Given a JUNG Graph G={V,E} and an edge E1, find the nodes/vertices
>   that  E1 connects and delete the vertex if it is a leaf node.

So, there are two parts:

1. Finding the vertices that are connected by a given edge E1.
2. Find if a given vertex is a leaf node?

Are these two operations directly possible in JUNG. If not, can someone suggest an alternate way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) `Graph.getIncidentVertices(E e1)`

(2) You don't define what you mean by "leaf node", but assuming that you're referring to a directed graph and a vertex that has one incoming edge and no outgoing edges, that's easy: 
`Graph.getIncomingEdges().size() == 1`

`Graph.getOutgoingEdges().isEmpty())`

If the graph is not a multigraph, you can also do this:
`Graph.getPredecessorCount() == 1`

`Graph.getSuccessorCount() == 0`

The Javadoc for JUNG is pretty good; you should consider browsing it before asking questions of this kind: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html

Comment: I actually tried this already. It later turned out that there was a bug in the application that was not giving me the results as expected. Sorry, I forgot to delete the questions. And I completely agree that JUNG has one of the best documentations compared to other tools of the same kind! Thanks you and the rest of your team!